# Understand how this M.2 B+M Key SSD can work via PCIe Adapter Card with 2 slots (both 1 B and 1 M slot)?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, sata, pci-express

**Understand how the M.2 B+M Key SSD can work via PCIe Adapter Card with 2 slots (both 1 B and 1 M slot)?**

We recently bought a Sandisk SSD X400 M.2 (B+M Key) to do some sample tests, see how it works and are having issues. Details below.

---

Read these articles around B/ M key SSDs & slots and Sandisk datasheets etc, but still not clear:

- https://rog.asus.com/13552014/maximus-motherboards/buying-an-m-2-ssd-how-to-tell-which-is-which/
- http://electronicdesign.com/blog/what-s-difference-between-m2-modules
- https://www.sandisk.com/business/computing/x400

  - https://www.sandisk.com/content/dam/sandisk-main/en_us/assets/resources/enterprise/data-sheets/X400-datasheet-v1-1.pdf
  - https://www.sandisk.com/content/dam/sandisk-main/en_us/assets/resources/enterprise/data-sheets/x400-ssd-for-boot-drives-data-sheet.pdf

---

We have a PCIe card (driver less/ transparent) that has 2 slots that support the following:

- M key Slot - PCIe 3.0 x 4 (PCIe 2.0 Compatible)
- B key Slot - SATA (6gbps)

Dell Vostro 230  + Windows 8.1

- Intel Core i3 4150 @ 3.5 Ghz - Haswell 22nm
- Motherboard: 0T1D10
- BIOS: A06
- Date 8/19/2014 (Probably needs to be updated - will do anyways)

We put the X400 in the M - key slot and cannot see any storage or indication of its availability.

- Can it be used via a native M-key slot on a motherboard?
- **Can it be used (even as storage) on the M-key of the PCIe card or only B-key via SATA?**
  (currently not trying to boot from it)
- **Can it be used later to boot via PCIe card - M and/ or B keys?**
  (On another machine, assuming its BIOS supports booting from such)

PS: I'm thinking, even if BIOS support for PCIe booting is not there, shouldn't we be able to access the storage, atleast? Does it need special drivers in Win 8.1?

Comment: “I'm thinking, even if BIOS support for PCIe booting is not there, shouldn't we be able to access the storage, atleast?” Yes.

Comment: @DanielB - Wasnt able to see via M key, but just attached via B key + SATA cable. Visible. So, what can I do to get it working via M key i.e. PCIe?

Comment: Datasheet says: SATA | SAS | PCIe, so I am guessing it should work via PCIe as well. But why is it not?

Answer (score 3):

The datasheet indicates multiple times that this SSD only supports the SATA protocol. That of course also means it can be used in a (true) dual-personality M.2 slot. It won't work with PCIe, though.

[According to my favorite price comparison website](http://geizhals.de/?cat=hdssd&xf=1035_SanDisk%7E4832_3), SanDisk does not offer any M.2 SSD with PCIe connectivity.

The part of the datasheet you're referring to, in the right column of the first page, only has SATA highlighted.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2#Form_factors_and_keying), both B and M keyed connections offer native SATA connectivity, which is what this SSD requires.

Comment: From what I read I thought it supported all 3 and thats why it was written so. Thanks. Just the way there are dual personality M.2 slots are there dual/ triple (SAS??) personality SSDs? PS: What is the definition of a dual personality Slot?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1130348/are-there-dual-triple-personality-m-2-ssds-that-support-pcie-nvme-sata-just-l

Comment: Sorry I forgot about your questions, I fell ill. You should probably also accept this answer. Or do you need additional clarification on this issue specifically?