# Dual/ triple personality M.2 SSDs that support PCIe NVMe + SATA just like dual personality M.2 slots (B+M) support? How to find/ identify them?

Tags: ssd, sata, pci-express, m.2, nvme

This is a little tidbit question I posted on a comment on the below mentioned question.

> "Of course also means it can be used in a (true) dual-personality M.2 slot. It won't work with PCIe, though."

"**Just the way there are dual personality M.2 slots are there dual/ triple (SAS??) personality SSDs?**"

I got a bunch of negatives on this question of mine but there's still no easy way to find, identify & determine PCIe / NVMe/ SATA properties of an SSD especially those with B + M dual connectors:

[Understand how this M.2 B+M Key SSD can work via PCIe Adapter Card with 2 slots (both 1 B and 1 M slot)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125065/understand-how-this-m-2-bm-key-ssd-can-work-via-pcie-adapter-card-with-2-slots)

Read these and a few more articles as well at the time:

- https://rog.asus.com/13552014/maximus-motherboards/buying-an-m-2-ssd-how-to-tell-which-is-which/
- http://electronicdesign.com/blog/what-s-difference-between-m2-modules

PS: Similar question but no answer posted. We need a SU Wiki for this subject area.

[NVMe support - implicit or explicit?](https://superuser.com/questions/1028996/nvme-support-implicit-or-explicit)

Also mentioned on a comment here by Ramhound:

> "**M.2 x4 Socket 3, with M Key**, type 2242/2260/2280/22110 storage devices **support (both SATA & PCIE mode)**" *indicates to me* **both AHCI support and NVMe support** but that is just me. Now If you want to boot to the device, that ius entirely up to the OS, after POST. "

Answer (score 3):

There are no dual-personality SSDs. Source: Current offerings.
That's a given, of course, because it would be very complex to build a controller that connects to all necessary pins on the M.2 connector. The controller would also have to support running in both a SATA and PCIe mode. And last but not least, the controller would have to detect which connection to make. AFAIK, sensing is not a part of the M.2 connector, however.

So, while technically possible (probably), it won't ever be economical.

SAS is also entirely unrelated because it is not used in consumer-grade PCs. There would be no benefit in providing SATA/PCIe connectivity for SAS devices.

It's also NVMe vs AHCI and SATA vs PCIe. *The only way* to find out what protocol and connection the SSD uses is to look at the specifications.

A PCIe SSD could use whatever proprietary protocol the manufacturer decides on.

Comment: Question updated with @Ramhound  comment here - http://superuser.com/questions/1028996/nvme-support-implicit-or-explicit - Seems to say there are some? I'm not clear on it.

Comment: Just saw you posted an answer there - Will read it up

Comment: Ramhound’s comment is about the slot, not the storage device that would be installed in the slot.